# Where's rpmfusion? - CentOS7 as desktop/multimedia system

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm

I am currently looking at Centos, because I am really getting fed up with having stuff changed or having to reinstall my system every 6 - 9 months or so, or running a system without any updates.

Now I am fully aware that this step to Centos (or RHEL or ScientificLinux for that matter) comes at the price of reduced software availability and older packages in general.

But since Centos now has a working version of KDE4 available, and I generally see Firefox as an "the older, the better" software nowadays, this at first seems not too bad.

And I don't really need to many other things (vlc, anaconda (python stuff), a hand full of browsers, wine and openTTD) I should be able to be happy with it.

Just enable rpmfusion and epel, and that's it.

Just that it isn't. Epel works, but rpmfusion does not exist (anymore? yet?). There is only a repo for Centos6 and 5, and searching for info about it, I only find stuff about enabling it for 6, two mailing list entries of people asking for it, one mentioning "infrastructure issues" and of course lots of blog posts of the "just copy and paste this, and this and this and that and you are good to go".

So what's happening?

**Is rpmfusion dead?**

**Do I just have to wait a bit, till they are finished?**

**Has it been renamed/moved?**

**Is there another, generally accepted, large repo?**

On the latter point, it seems like atrpms and nux-dextop are at least [not warned about](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories), and could offer what I need, but http://atrpms.net/ seems offline, and nux seems like a one-man show, and I don't really trust those.

Comment: You can install rpmfusion for RHEL 6 and it will work for many packages, but not for all. The ones it doesn't work for, rpmfusion has a dependency for a specific older version of a library that you may not have. If you're doing a fresh install, try to do the rpmfusion installs BEFORE doing "yum upgrade". And, of course, there's always source builds (sh configure && make && make install) or use CentOS 6 which apparently doesn't EOL for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rpmfusion infra lacks of volunteer. For some reason they decided to move to git and not branch until they finish the move:
https://lists.rpmfusion.org/pipermail/rpmfusion-developers/2014-October/017494.html
This lasts more then year unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, good - or rather bad - to know. But that is really badly communicated on the rpmfusion homepage. So I guess I have to wait, until I can give CentOS a try.

Comment: Also check out Dag Wieers' repo http://dag.wiee.rs/rpm/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: It appears that CERN (http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/) has been creating packages for CentOS 7. I created an ad hoc .repo file at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/CENTOS/bctest.repo (the names/etc are wrong, but the URLs should work) and `yum list | grep bctest` seems to show there are quite a few useful packages there, though, even combined with epel and the default repo, not necessarily everything you need.**

I ran into similar issues and decided to install CentOS 6.8 instead:

- Despite the homepage centos.org warning

> Legacy versions of CentOS are no longer supported. For historical
>   purposes, CentOS keeps an archive of older versions. If you're
>   absolutely sure you need an older version then click here

https://wiki.centos.org/Download states that CentOS 6 
  support will continue for at least 4 years. Hopefully, within that 
  time, CentOS 7 will become usable and people can upgrade to it.

- Per wikipedia 
  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_releases), CentOS 6.8 
  was released 10 May 2016, only a few months ago, long after CentOS 7 
  was released (on 7 July 2014). In fact, excluding CentOS 7.3, this 
  is the most recent "distribution" CentOS has released. I sense the 
  CentOS creators realize that 7 is too unstable for use, so keep 
  updating 6.
- As you note, rpmfusion is supported for 6, but not for 7. Many 
  rpmfusion 6 packages work in CentOS 7, but you get some ugly errors, 
  and important packages like ffmpeg, mencoder/mplayer, and vlc, won't 
  install.
- Of course, you can install from source, but even this is ugly, 
  since source installs require you to install dependencies by hand 
  (or lose functionality if you choose not to).
- CentOS 6 is a stable, trusted, supported distribution with a 
  strong RPM base. CentOS 7 seems to suffer from the "odd number 
  rule": it exists, people use it, and it even has a few repos, but 
  it's just not that stable or easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

> So what's happening?

Development [continues](http://lists.rpmfusion.org/pipermail/rpmfusion-developers/).

> Is rpmfusion dead?

No it's just unreasonably slow for EL7, but it's alive for Fedora users.

> Do I just have to wait a bit, till they are finished?

No; 3 years is more than "a bit" in the software realm, but they might get it released before EL8 (2019?).

> Has it been renamed/moved?

No.

> Is there another, generally accepted, large repo?

No. [nux](https://li.nux.ro/repos.html) or a manual install are your options for EL7. So you might want to use Fedora or Debian if you want those types of packages from a popular/distribution repository.